# multifileUpload from single browse and select

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload

How can I build a multiple file upload feature similar to that of gmail.
I should be able to select multiple files by holding ctrl or select all the files in the folder.

Comment: Can you include `html` tried at Question?

Comment: you can use https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/. 
Also, for multiple file upload you should have "multiple" attribute in your input type file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go via input method of the form, then there is a simple attribute to select multiple files:

```
<form>
<input type="file" name="uploadfile" multiple />
</form>
```

the `multiple` attribute can help you get your way, i.e. selecting more than one file by using control/shift button, or by mouse...

Hope this helps.. :)